# Download one column instead of entire class from Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to set up a table populated with the usernames and low resolution profile pictures of the users of the app. I don't want to download the rest of the columns from Parse because all of this information is unnecessary. Is there a way to download all of the rows from a specific column in a Parse class? I am looking for an answer in Swift.

The code I am using right now is:

```
var query = PFQuery(classnamed: "_User")
query.getObject()
```

Comment: Take a look at Cloud Code. You can do exactly what you want with CC.

Comment: Or reconsider your table to have a pointer to the images, but the  cloud code option doesn't need any changes in the current schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. From the [docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-basic/iOS):

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
query.selectKeys(["low_res_profile_pic"])
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    // objects in results will only contain the low_res_profile_pic field
  }
}
```